# how to get a list of supported image formats in gd?

Tags: php, gd

as the title says, how do i get a list of supported formats, *at runtime* ?

i *hope* there is a better way to do it, but this *almost* works (i say almost because it says `Gif Read` and `Gif Create` rather than just `Gif`, and it also looks quite hackish+fragile, if in the future something other than an image format happens to match the format `'Blabla Support' => true` then it will be accidentally included as well, and vice-versa):

```php
function get_gd_supported_formats(): array
{
    // sample return:
    array(
        'FreeType',
        'GIF Read',
        'GIF Create',
        'JPEG',
        'PNG',
        'WBMP',
        'XPM',
        'XBM',
        'WebP',
        'BMP'
    );
    $ret = [];
    foreach (gd_info() as $name => $supported) {
        if (! $supported) {
            continue;
        }
        $supportEndNeedle = " Support";
        $supportEndPos = strrpos($name, $supportEndNeedle);
        if (false === $supportEndPos || strlen($name) !== ($supportEndPos + strlen($supportEndNeedle))) {
            continue;
        }
        $name = substr($name, 0, $supportEndPos);
        $ret[] = $name;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: _“it says Gif Read and Gif Create rather than just Gif”_ - as it should; apparently, the ability to _read_ GIFs, and the ability to _write_ GIFs, are two separate things in terms of the GDlib, so you might encounter setups where only either one of the two is available.

Comment: @04FS right you are, in the context of gd_info(), but strictly speaking, `Gif Create` is not an image format, `Gif` is an image format, and i want to get a list of all formats (and pretty much succeeded, but in a hacky fragile way, i was hoping there was a proper way to do it; maybe there isn't)